# Reading Tensorflow Record Files, does not work after first run

Tags: tensorflow

I have a small block of code that reads in data from some TFRecord files. If I run the code from an ipython notebook, it works fine the first time I execute the block. But the same block of code produces an error if I try to execute it a second time without restarting the kernel (Error: StatusNotOK: Not found: FetchOutputs node DecodeRaw_2:0: not found). The code is shown below. Do I need to close/clear/reinitialize something in order to have the code run properly multiple times?

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename_list)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
image = []
label = []
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    tf_image, tf_label = read_and_decode(filename_queue)
    for i in range(len(filename_list)):
        image.append(sess.run(tf_image))
        label.append(sess.run(tf_label))

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Note that read_and_decode() is taken from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/code/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_reader.py)

Comment: try `tf.reset_default_graph()` before running the snippet the second time

Comment: That did it! Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues in the code in the question.

1. The first, [as Yaroslav pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35468717/3574081) is that all of the ops are added to the same graph. The means that when you call [`tf.train.start_queue_runners()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/train.html#start_queue_runners) (or run the [`tf.initialize_all_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#initialize_all_variables) op) the session will be doing work that is proportional to the number of times that you've run this code snippet. You can call [`tf.reset_default_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/framework.html#reset_default_graph) in between invocations to this code, but a cleaner way to isolate things might be to declare a separate graph each time:

   ```
   with tf.Graph().as_default():  # Declares a new graph for the life of the block.
       filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename_list)
       init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
       image = []
       label = []
       with tf.Session() as sess:
           # ...
           coord.join(threads)
   ```
2. The second issue is that the separate calls to `sess.run(tf_image)` and `sess.run(tf_label)` means that the association between image and label is lost. When you call `sess.run(tf_image)` you consume an image *and* a label from the reader, but discard the label (and vice versa for `sess.run(tf_label)`. The correct solution is to fetch them both in the same step:

   ```
   image_val, label_val = sess.run([tf_image, tf_label])
   image.append(image_val)
   label.append(label_val)
   ```
3. The final issue—which could cause problems even if you reset the graph—is that the code adds nodes to the graph after calling `tf.train.start_queue_runners()`. There is a possibility of data races on the TensorFlow graph, because [`read_and_decode()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/fdf2b0e9dc0017ab7fe38893b01e6adffa43c289/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_reader.py#L55) adds nodes to the graph, while the parallel queue runners concurrently read it, and the `tf.Graph` isn't thread safe.

   The best way to deal with this is to define all of your graph before starting the queue runners:

   ```
   with tf.Graph().as_default():
       filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename_list)
       image = []
       label = []
       tf_image, tf_label = read_and_decode(filename_queue)

       with tf.Session() as sess:
          coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
          threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

          for i in range(len(filename_list)):
              image_val, label_val = sess.run([tf_image, tf_label])
              image.append(image_val)
              label.append(label_val)

          coord.request_stop()
          coord.join(threads)
   ```

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks for your detailed comments. I learned a lot!

Answer (score 1):

By default tf. commands append to default graph with new names. You can use tf.reset_default_graph() before running the snippet the second time to clear the default graph.